# sending email for birthday don't show emails

Tags: php, mysql, email, pdo

I have issue with email in my table when I try to send mails for birthdays..

Here is the printscreen, if you see the table in the right, there are 2 users with birthdays but in the input below of div error is empty... and say "there is not birthday for today":

[image]

```
<?php 
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM USERS WHERE f_nac >= CURDATE() AND f_nac < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY f_nac ASC");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $email = ($row['email'].", "); 
}
$largo=strlen($email);
if ($largo>2)
    $email=substr($email,0,$largo-2);
} else {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">No hay cumplea&ntilde;eros!</div>';
  };
?>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
```

How can I show the emails to send the mail to them?

the two users have emails and the row in the table is "f_nac" with type "date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CUR_DATE()` is in 2014, the birthdays are in 1975 and 1978. You have to ignore the year when you're comparing.

```
SELECT email 
FROM USERS 
WHERE MONTH(f_nac) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(f_nac) = DAY(NOW())
```

In your `while` loop you're overwriting `$email`, not appending to it. It should be:

```
$email = '';
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $email .= ($row['email'].", "); 
}
```

Comment: See the updated answer, you're not concatenating to $email properly.

Comment: That's it! Thanks Barmar! if I could give you more points. Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing currently is extracting the data from SQL (daily) and composing and email to send the wish manually daily. What if I suggest you a better approach ?

There is an application called [Wishing Application](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app) which can send birthday and work anniversary mailer with a breeze.

At minimal it just need two things **excel file** with wish details (Date, name, email) and a configuration file (**application.properties**) and that is it, you are good to go.

Further there various [options to run](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Running) the application locally (Command line, foreground, background, docker, windows scheduler, unix cron etc) Cloud.

Application is [highly configurable](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Configurations-unleashed) , you can configure various details like:

- Workbook loading options
- Image options to send with wishes.
- SMTP Configurations
- Other application level configurations like, when to send wish, belated wish, logging etc.

  Disclaimer : I am the owner of the application